# How can make a plot in python to start from value x from X axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I am new with matplotlib and I have a function that I want to plot. At the moment I have the next code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(f)
```

The problem is that I want the function to start plotting from the value 10 of X axis, not from 0. How can I do it?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html Will this solve your problem?

Comment: Not really... I mean, I want the plot show all the values from 0, but I want the function to start plotting at value 10, for example. So I would have the first 10 elements as blank, and then the function would start plotting.

Comment: Can you share with us the code and a similar function?

Comment: If you set ``f(x)=NaN`` for ``x<10``, you might get what you want.

Comment: @jartymcfly You need to alter your data so that it plots only some specific data. But we need more code. Hint : Look at [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: Exactly! f(x)=NaN for x<10 was what I needed. Tjanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to achieve this.

We are passing x-axis values as the range we want to be plotted say between 10 and 15 ,

```
x = numpy.linspace(10,15,100) #hundred points between 10 and 15
y = numpy.sin(x)/x            #function
```

Now we set xlim to wherever the range we want to show the graph from say 0, 15

```
plt.plot(x,y) 
plt.xlim((0,15))
plt.show()
```

[image: plot starts from 10 while the x-axis starts from 0]

Answer (score 2):

```
# Importing data here
data = pd.read_csv('google.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')

# Creating weekly series 
weeks = data.asfreq('W', method='ffill')
print(weeks.head())

# Plotting weeks starting from 2015 here 
weeks.loc['2015':].plot() # here x-axis value is starting from '2015' 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [plot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you can specify the x coordinates in the first parameters (optionnal) :

```
plot([x], y, [fmt], data=None, **kwargs)
```

If you are plotting a function with numpy, you do something like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
x = np.arange(10.0, 20.0, 0.1)
f = your_function(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, f)
plt.show()
```

See more examples here : [matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html)